# Nuget updating-package removes reference from project

Tags: .net, package, nuget

I'm encountering an issue with nuget package manager. After updating from svn I did a restore on nuget package and I updated it by Update-Pakcage command. After the update the old reference was deleted from csproj file, but a new one was not inserted. And this is causes a lot of problem in the further testing.

p.s. the package file was updated properly with new version of package.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I am facing the same issue while updating nuget pacakges. Please let me know if you found a resolution.